# How can I run ROS2 on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: 22.04, ros

I have issue with having unavailable to run ROS2 on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

Comment: More info is needed. There is noting here to use to offer any help.

Comment: Here are older instructions on how to run ROS2 on Ubuntu 22.04 from ROS.org: https://docs.ros.org/en/dashing/Installation/Ubuntu-Install-Binary.html I think cardboardcode's link is newer.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, only **ROS2 Humble Hawksbill** is available on **Ubuntu 22.04 LTS**. You could have a look at the [ROS2 Humble Documentation](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Installation/Ubuntu-Install-Debians.html) for the installation instructions.

To ensure that it is available via `sudo apt-get install` commands, run the following commands:

```bash
apt-cache policy | grep universe
```

You should see:

```bash
500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 Packages
    release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=amd64
```

If you don't, please follow the instructions under [Setup Sources](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Installation/Ubuntu-Install-Debians.html#setup-sources) to rectify it.